# Use input number with currency values and keep trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic for an iOS app, my issue is that I can't keep trailing zeros in currency values when using an input with type number.

I need input number so the appropriate keyboard opens in iOS. ParseFloat toFixed wont work as it produces a string / exception. If I put the value 25.20 in the input it changes to 25.2, is there any solution to this?

```
$scope.total = 25.20;

<input type="number" name="total" value="{{total}}" placeholder="total amount" ng-model="total" min="1" max="2500" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Change to `type="text"`

Comment: that'll open a text keyboard in iOS without numbers, I'd like to open the number keyboard by default

Comment: Maybe because $scope.total is a number and not a String? Try to convert the value to a string and then format it in the way that want. Numeral.js could help.

Comment: i dont understand how that would help @dlopez

Comment: Look at this. I used it in node, but this also works on a browser.
25.20.toString() => 25.2
25.20.toFixed(2) => 25.20

Comment: Expected `250.20` to be a number